# How can I make Vue to show up on my VSCode intellicense instead of VTTCue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, in .js file, whenever I type Vue, VSCode always displays VTTCue at the top of the intellicense.

I do not want to press Escape key every time I type Vue (because otherwise VSCode will overwrite my text with VTTCue when I press `(` character)

Is there any good way to avoid this? Extension? Settings?

I would appreciate anything at this point.

[image]